# Loading product in Magento 2 issue with PhpUnit tests

Tags: magento2, phpunit

This is my method, for which I want to write a unit test:

```
private $productRepository;

public function __construct(
    ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
)
{
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getProductName(int $productEntityId) : string
{
    $myProduct = $this->productRepository->getById($productEntityId);
    return (string) $myProduct->getName();
}
```

and my test:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider productEntityIds
 * @param $productEntityId
 */
public function testGetProductName($productEntityId)
{
    $this->assertInternalType('string', $this->myCustomClass->getProductName($productEntityId));
    //assertIsString().
}

public function productEntityIds()
{
    return [
        [1]
        [2],
        [3],
        [5],
        ['myString']
    ];
}
```

When I run my test, I am receiving the following error message:
`Error: Call to a member function getName() on null`

If I call the method( `getProductName()` ), in a cronjob or an observer I successfully received the product name. But If call it from the phpunit test , I am receiving that error. Does anyone know why ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you update your whole unit test class?

Answer (score 0):

Is the product repository mock returning product mock?

```
$productMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Product::class);

$productMock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getName')
    ->willReturn('Some nice product');

$productRepositoryMock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('getById')
    ->willReturn($productMock);
```

http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/phpunit-best-practice.php